# using fitted() on output from lm with dummy variables

Tags: r, linear-regression, prediction

```
reg_ss <- predict(lm(stem_d~stand_id*yr,ss))
fitted.values(reg_ss)

#Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I have tried this with `fitted()` and `fitted.values()` and receive the same error.

`stand_id` is a factor with 300+ levels and `yr` is an integer 1-19, but both are numbers.

I have data on tree stem density collected in stands every 2-3 years for 20 years. I want to run a linear regression and predict stem density for stands in the years between samplings, i.e. use data from year 1 and 3 to predict stem density in year 2.

Any suggestions on how I can get predicted values using `fitted()` or any other method would be greatly appreciated. I suspect it has something to do with dummy variables assigned to the categories but can't seem to find any information on a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your problem how to get the predicted values?

Comment: yes I just need the predicted values of stem density for the stand year combinations we did not sample.

Comment: Then look MrFlick's answer, or if it doesn't work say why not :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want fitted values, you should not be calling `predict()` first.

```
reg_ss <- lm(stem_d~stand_id*yr,ss)
predict(reg_ss)
fitted(reg_ss)
```

When you don't pass new data to predict, it's basically doing the same thing as `fitted` so you get essentially the same values back. Both `fitted` and `predict` will return a simple named vector. You cannot use `fitted` on a named vector (hence the error message).

If you want to predict unobserved values, you need to pass a `newdata=` parameter to `predict()`. You should pass in a data.frame with columns named "stand_id" and "yr" just like `ss`. Make sure to match up the factor levels as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!                                          So both predicted() and fitted() just return the error message.      "#Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" - So I do not get any results. I will try creating newdata = as described but how do I match up the factor levels? The combination of unique combinations of these factors is in the thousands. Should I use something like expand.grid to create a dataframe with all possible combos and then pass that in as newdata = ?

Comment: Then please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that recreates the same error message. This runs just fine for me if I define `ss<-data.frame(stand_id=runif(10),stem_d=rnorm(10), yr=1:10)`

Comment: If I understand the ss you created, it has continuous variables for stand_id and yr where my data has stand_id as a factor and yr is an integer. Would this cause the error?

Comment: It also works just fine with `ss<-data.frame(stand_id=factor(sample(1:3, 10, replace=T)),stem_d=rnorm(10), yr=1L:10L)`. I need *you* to come you with a reproducible example that doesn't work because everything I come up with works just fine.

Comment: So I figured out how to pass in the newdata and it works now. Thanks for all your help.